# Does anyone know what $H'_{m}$ means in this group theory paper by Miller?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, notation, involutions

https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/tmj1911/17/0/17_0_88/_pdf

Page 90, third paragraph, where it says

> "By continuing this process we arrive at a group $H_m$ containing the central of G and each of the operators $s_1, s_2, ... , s_m$ and involving only commutative involutions. If these operators generate $H_{m}'$ we represent $H_{m}'$ by $H_{m}$. If this is not the case we let $H_{m}$ represent the subgroup of index 2 under $H_{m}'$ generated by all its involutions."

I don't believe the notation has anything to do with commutator/derived subgroups and I couldn't find any explanation of it either on the paper itself or on the textbook he wrote unless it is related to whatever is going on in section 14 here https://archive.org/details/theoryapplicatio00milluoft/page/34 but that still doesn't help me make sense of what he means on the paper.

Comment: Why don't you think it has to do with commutator subgroup/derived subgroup? That has been standard notation for quite a while.

Comment: @PaulPlummer because throughout the paper and his textbook he refers to commutator/derived subgroups and never uses that notation for them, plus trying to follow his construction with specific groups it doesn't make sense. This paper is 100 years old so I guess it's not unreasonable to assume he means something else. And if that's what it is then I'm still confused about what's going on in the bit I quoted